# How to process JSON field from relation database with PYSPARK?

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to process JSON column from PostgreSQL database.
I am able to connect to database using:

```
import os
import pyspark
import findspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
findspark.init(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'])

# DB credentials
user = os.environ['EVENTS_DEV_UID']
password = os.environ['EVENTS_DEV_PWD']
host = os.environ['EVENTS_DEV_HOST']
port = os.environ['EVENTS_DEV_PORT']
db = os.environ['EVENTS_DEV_DBNAME']

# Initiate spark session
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SQLContext(sc)

# Set properties
properties = {"user": user, "password": password, "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"}

# Load data
df = spark.read.jdbc(
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://' + host + ':' + port + '/' + db,
    table = 'events',
    properties = properties)
```

The problem starts with casting JSON field. Spark doesn't recognize struct format of `params`. When I print schema:

```
df.printSchema()
```

root 
   |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true) 
   |-- name: string (nullable = true) 
   |-- params: string (nullable = true)

When I try to cast string to struct:

```
df = df.withColumn('params', df.params.cast('struct'))
```

I am getting following error:

```
ParseException: '\nDataType struct is not supported.(line 1, pos 0)\n\n== SQL ==\nstruct\n^^^\n'
```

I guess problem is the escape characters. Anybody has idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

`"struct"` is not a valid casting type. You can define your own `UDF` using python's `json.loads` function.
Let's start with a sample data frame:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([[1, "a", "{\"a\":1, \"b\":2}"], [2, "b", "{\"a\":3, \"b\":4}"]])\
    .toDF(["col1", "col2", "json_col"])
df.show()

    +----+----+--------------+
    |col1|col2|      json_col|
    +----+----+--------------+
    |   1|   a|{"a":1, "b":2}|
    |   2|   b|{"a":3, "b":4}|
    +----+----+--------------+
```

Then the output `StructType` would have schema:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StructField, StructType
schema = StructType([StructField("a", IntegerType()), StructField("b", IntegerType())])
```

You cannot cast `StringType` to `StructType`, hence the `UDF`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
import json
json_load = psf.udf(json.loads, schema)
```

Now we can process `json_col`:

```py
df_parsed = df.withColumn("parsed_json", json_load("json_col"))
df_parsed.show()
df_parsed.printSchema()

    +----+----+--------------+-----------+
    |col1|col2|      json_col|parsed_json|
    +----+----+--------------+-----------+
    |   1|   a|{"a":1, "b":2}|      [1,2]|
    |   2|   b|{"a":3, "b":4}|      [3,4]|
    +----+----+--------------+-----------+

    root
     |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
     |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
     |-- json_col: string (nullable = true)
     |-- parsed_json: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
     |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
```

You can also try passing the schema directly when loading the data frame.